# Set network card to AP mode in OSX

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, command-line, wireless-access-point

I am trying to do OSX's internet sharing from the command line and there doesn't seem to be a command for it, so I'm trying to do it manually by turning the network card to access point mode. I can't seem to find anything about how to turn the wireless card into AP mode on the mac. Linux would use iwconfig (which OSX doesn't have) and I've monitored the files that network sharing opens, but no dice so far.

It looks related to wifid, but the documentation for wifid only says "Don't invoke wifid directly". Also played with the airportd command, but it doesn't seem to let the card go into AP mode. There must be a way to do it, since internet sharing creates an access point.

TL;DR:Does anyone know how to turn on Internet Sharing from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no command line tool or public API for doing this. Your best bet for doing it programmatically might be AppleScripting the UI for the Sharing panel in System Preferences.

Comment: This is as good as it will get for now, I think. Thanks for the help